# System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException

Tags: asp.net

I keep getting the following error when trying to run an application in the production environment with "anonymous" authentication and hardcoded username.

When I turn on basic authentication, which then prompts for username/password everything works like a charm. but I need to get the hardcoded version to work as well. Can't figure out whats going on.

Everything works perfectly on another server.

> Exception Details: System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: An operations
>   error occurred.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072020): An operations error occurred.]
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail) +781
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() +44
>   System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_SchemaEntry() +49
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.IsContainer(DirectoryEntry
>   de) +62
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx..ctor(DirectoryEntry
>   ctxBase, Boolean ownCtxBase, String username, String password,
>   ContextOptions options) +123
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.CreateContextFromDirectoryEntry(DirectoryEntry
>   entry) +234
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInit()
>   +497
>
> [PrincipalOperationException: An operations error occurred.]
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInit()
>   +534256
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit()
>   +61
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
>   +141
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
>   +42
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext
>   context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String
>   identityValue, DateTime refDate) +27
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext
>   context, String identityValue) +95
>   SERT_BO.ADHelper.UserBelongsToGrp(String adGroup, String sAMAccountName, String& emailAddr, String& fullName) in
>   D:\SERT\BusinessObjects\SERT_BO\ADHelper.cs:199
>   SERT_BO.UserSession.GetUserSession(String userName) in D:\SERT\BusinessObjects\SERT_BO\UserSession.cs:44
>   SERT.SetUserSession.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\SERT\SERT\SERT\SetUserSession.aspx.cs:23
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3064

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the issue was that the server was looking at the wrong AD controller. it had to be written out COMPLETELY.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check is that the AppPool in which the ASP.NET app is running has the right privileges. As a quick test you can set the identity of the AppPool to Local System and see if this solves the issue. If the problem is here, then you can set the application pool identity to a (domain?) user that has enough privileges on this server.

Comment: everything is identical in the application pool.